# Is there a comma like operator in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda

Specifically I'd like to run the code below. The problem is unlike C and JS which has a comma operator (`i=(1,2)` is 2) C# doesn't. AddRange does not return the list it's using so I'm stuck on this lambda. How do I write the lambda without using braces and return statement like the code under it?

```
var ls1 = new String[]{"one", "three"};
var ls2 = new String[]{"two", "four"};
var ls = (new[] {ls1, ls2}).Aggregate(new List<String>(), (l,r)=> (l.AddRange(r), l));
//var ls = (new[] {ls1, ls2}).Aggregate(new List<String>(), (l,r)=> {l.AddRange(r); return l;});
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ls));
```

Comment: Are you tied to Aggregate? what about `var ls = ls1.Concat(ls2).ToList();` If your real goal is to just write a expression with more than one statement in it you may need to built the expression manually without using a lambada and use `System.Linq.Expressions` instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: My goal is dealing with lambda's when the function I call returns void :(. I absolutely don't want to write return because it kind of wrecks the aesthetics of the lambda. If the return value was something, anything else I could get around it with`?:`.

Comment: Put the lambda inside the AddRange().   ls.AddRange(lambda)

Comment: @jdweng: Are you trying to do inception? The AddRange needs l, l comes from Aggregate, How do I put Aggregate in AddRange

Comment: ls.AddRange(string.Aggregate((ls1,ls2) => ls1 + ls2)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will extension method work for you? It is not like (1,2) operator, but achieves goal of avoiding return in lambda

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static List<string> AddRangeAndReturn(this List<string> list, IEnumerable<string> itemsToAdd)
    {
        list.AddRange(itemsToAdd);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
var ls = (new[] {ls1, ls2}).Aggregate(new List<String>(), (l,r)=> l.AddRangeWithReturn(r) );
```

Comment: I'll probably just do the commented out line or this if I have a lot of AddRangeAndReturn. It's too bad there's nothing like the comma operator